# opening a web site via the bookmark bar results in focus not going to web page

Tags: keyboard, safari, bookmarks

When I open a link from my bookmark bar (either by command-option-1, etc) or by clicking on the bookmark bar item, the cursor focus will not be on the web page.  This requires that you were on a new window or new tab that was on the "favorites" (as set in safari preferences).

My test case is google, but my real problem is a captive portal that I use every day.  This happens on any web page where a text field should automatically have the focus.

Steps to recreate:

1) Make sure safari preferences set to new windows and new tabs open in favorites.

2) Add a bookmark to https://www.google.com/ and making that the first bookmark in your bookmark bar.

3) Open a new window (command-n) and then open the google bookmark (command-option-1).

Result: the focus will not be on the google search box.

Question: How do I fix this? Is there a setting I can make this work?

(If I tab through all the controls at the top of the page -- forward/back/url bar/all the bookmarks -- 23 tabs in my case.)

version: Safari 13.0.2

Comment: Does this only happen with Google or also with other web pages? Also, what exactly is your question here?

Comment: Nope, works fine for me. your unexpected behavior may be the result of an extension, a couple of preferences interacting badly or just damaged preferences. I'd clear caches (develop menu) turn off ALL plug ins/extensions, export your bookmarks and delete all Safari related items in your library forlde

Comment: Good questions...I updated the post.  It happens on any web page where a text box should have the focus when the web page loads (search engines, captive portals, etc).  My question is how do I fix this or work around it without reverting back to the mouse.